# Reading the text value or number from an image using node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to read a number from an image using Node.js.

I am parsing the image using canvas and then reading the image but it gives me the binary data for image but I need the number value that image contains.

Comment: that number or text is inside that image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, obviously you can't just read data off the image and get the text you need.

You need to interpret the image with some OCR ([Optical character recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)) software.

What I could suggest if you are keen on using NodeJS is the [node-tesseract](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-tesseract) module. Make sure to do as the Installation guide says because you also need to install the [tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) software as well as the module.

Comment: No error but when i am consoling the text it shows me blank

Comment: tesseract.process(__dirname + '/2.jpg',function(err, text) {
              if(err) {
                console.error(err);
              } else {
                console.log(text);
              }
            });

Comment: Edit the question, please, and format the code correctly.

Comment: tesseract.process(__dirname + '/ate.jpg',function(err, text) {
              if(err) {
                console.error(err);
              } else {
                console.log(text);
              }

Comment: is there any special type of image for this module(e.g. jpg,png)

Comment: You won't be able to read captcha with it since the text is very unreadable. You'd need to use a service like 2captcha or deathbycaptcha.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
npm install tesseract.js
```

Then
include file in node.js

```
var Tesseract = require('tesseract.js');
```

Then

```
Tesseract.recognize(
  'https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png',
  'eng',
  { logger: m => console.log(m) }
).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
  console.log(text);
})
```

Comment: do we need to install external software?

Answer (score 1):

First, do install `tesseract` in your machine by doing the given steps from this [tessdocs](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Home.html)(tesseract documentation).

Once you are done with the installation please try the steps from the 
[above comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60057749/9396459)